# Inserting UTF-32 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, encoding, utf, emoji

I'm testing UTF-32 characters (specifically emojis) with SQL Server (2008 R2, 10.5) and at this stage I'm checking if the server supports the given code

For this case I'm using the [:rose](http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/226/nature/rose) with the following query

`SELECT '' + nchar(0x1F339) + 'test'`

which returns back in Management Studio with `(NULL)`.

What format do I need to encode the character to have it not return null in SQL Server

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server only supports UCS-2, which is currently (almost) the same as UTF-16. So exactly 2 bytes per character and all that.

Comment: Downvoted, because currently SqlServer do support SC-collations, and this answer is outdated.

Comment: It was outdated even when written; UTF-16 emojis use 4 bytes, not 2. 

Answer (score -1):

An idea, if I may. You can store the data in a BINARY or VARBINARY data field which doesn't care about encoding. You can then use a mapping table or external script to parse the binary into a text field replacing 0x1F339 with :rose: or your own custom forma for example.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's UTF-32, it has two be written as two UTF-16 characters:

```
-- Returns: test
SELECT '' + nchar(0xD83C) + nchar(0xDF39) + 'test'
```

You can find this code under "UTF-16 Hex (C Syntax)" title, following your link.

Also I have to recommend this article, because it was very helpful during investigation: [Unicode Escape Sequences Across Various Languages and Platforms (including Supplementary Characters)](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2019/06/26/unicode-escape-sequences-across-various-languages-and-platforms-including-supplementary-characters/)

Couple of options for those who are looking for answers:

> SQL Server technically does not have character escape sequences, but
> you can still create characters using either byte sequences or Code
> Points using the CHAR() and NCHAR() functions. We are only concerned
> with Unicode here, so we will only be using NCHAR().
>
> All versions:
>
> NCHAR(0 - 65535) for BMP Code Points (using an int/decimal value)
>
> NCHAR(0x0 - 0xFFFF) for BMP Code Points (using a binary/hex value)
>
> NCHAR(0 - 65535) + NCHAR(0 - 65535) for a Surrogate Pair / Two UTF-16
> Code Units
>
> NCHAR(0x0 - 0xFFFF) + NCHAR(0x0 - 0xFFFF) for a Surrogate Pair / Two
> UTF-16 Code Units
>
> CONVERT(NVARCHAR(size), 0xHHHH) for one or more characters in UTF-16
> Little Endian (“HHHH” is 1 or more sets of 4 hex digits)
>
> Starting in SQL Server 2012:
>
> If database’s default collation supports Supplementary Characters
> (collation name ends in _SC, or starting in SQL Server 2017 name
> contains *140* but does not end in _BIN*, or starting in SQL Server
> 2019 name ends in _UTF8 but does not contain _BIN2), then NCHAR() can
> be given Supplementary Character Code Points:
>
> decimal value can go up to 1114111
>
> hex value can go up to 0x10FFFF
>
> Starting in SQL Server 2019:
>
> “_UTF8” collations enable CHAR and VARCHAR data to use the UTF-8
> encoding:
>
> CONVERT(VARCHAR(size), 0xHH) for one or more characters in UTF-8 (“HH”
> is 1 or more sets of 2 hex digits)
>
> NOTE: The CHAR() function does not work for this purpose. It can only
> produce a single byte, and UTF-8 is only a single byte for values 0 –
> 127 / 0x00 – 0x7F.

Comment: First, your answer came 6 years too late. Second, the SQL Server version stated in the question (2008 R2) does not support SC-aware collations, they appeared only in 2012. Nor does it support UTF-8 in any capacity. Sure, you can split a UTF-32 character into 2 UTF-16 chars (probably?) and store them as such, but in any client application which isn't SC-aware they will look like hieroglyphs, or somesuch. Have you actually tried your advice on 2008 R2?

Comment: @RogerWolf Do you propose duplicating the entire stackoverflow for every version of the software peope asking questions about? This question is the first google result for "sqlserver utf-32", I need this answer here for myself at least.

Comment: in this case people usually add a note in the beginning of their answer, such as "For anyone looking to solve this with the current version...", or something along these lines. And it's definitely not a reason to downvote all the other answers to the question that were correct at the time of their writing (in case it's your downvotes, of course).